# VBS script to copy files and folders across network

Tags: file, vbscript, copy

I needed to copy all of my photos from my old laptop to my new laptop. This is a quick and dirty script that I put together (based on other scripts on this site) to copy files from one network location to another. I wanted the process to be able to recover in case of a network copy error because the total time to copy all of my photos was 40 hours.

sourceRoot and targetRoot is the beginning part of the file path to replace between locations. lastFileLog is a file used to keep track of the last file that was copied. This is needed to recover from a partial copy. Windows seems to allocate the full file size even when the file fails to copy. So I just keep track of the last file to copy it again on failure. objStartFolder is the starting path on the source network location.

```
'initialize paths
objStartFolder = "\\owner-pc\d\pics"
lastFileLog = "c:\Files\misc\archive.log"
sourceRoot = "\\owner-pc\d"
targetRoot = "c:\Files"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'read log
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(lastFileLog)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    replacefile= objFile.ReadLine
    Wscript.Echo "This file will be replaced: " & replacefile
Loop
objFile.Close

'copy files
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

'clear log
Set objFileLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile(lastFileLog,True)
objFileLog.Write ""
objFileLog.Close

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders

        Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path

        if not(objFSO.FolderExists(replace(Subfolder.Path,sourceRoot,targetRoot))) then
          objFSO.CreateFolder(replace(Subfolder.Path,sourceRoot,targetRoot))
        end if

        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles

            if not(objFSO.FileExists(replace(Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name,sourceRoot,targetRoot))) then 
              Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name

              Set objFileLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile(lastFileLog,True)
              objFileLog.Write Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
              objFileLog.Close

              objFSO.CopyFile Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name, replace(Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name,sourceRoot,targetRoot)

            elseif replacefile = Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name then
              Wscript.Echo "Replacing ... " & Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name  
              objFSO.CopyFile Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name, replace(Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name,sourceRoot,targetRoot),true            
            else
              Wscript.Echo "Skip ... " & Subfolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
            end if
        Next
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
end sub
```

Comment: note that you'll need to create an empty log file for the script to work for the first time. I was too lazy to add in the code to do it for you. for example in command window type:  echo >"c:\Files\misc\archive.log"

Answer (score 2):

For Folder: Try This.

```
Option Explicit
Dim obj,Itemcoll1,a,b
Set obj=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Function SelectFold1(Desc)
Set SelectFold1=obj.BrowseForFolder(0,Desc,0,"C:\Users\Mohammed Sajjad\Desktop\")
End Function

Set Itemcoll1=SelectFold1("Copy: ").Items
SelectFold1("Paste: ").CopyHere Itemcoll1 'Use MoveHere if you want to move
MsgBox "Completed"
```

For File:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objApp : Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objSHL : Set objSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Browse for Folder
'----------------------------------------------------------
Function SelectFold()
     Dim objFolder
     Set objFolder = objApp.BrowseForFolder(0,"Select a Folder",0,0)
     If objFolder Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Canceled"
     WScript.Quit
     Else
     SelectFold = objFolder.Self.Path & "\"
     End If
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------
'Browse for file
'----------------------------------------------------------
Function SelectFile()
Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
Dim tempFile : tempFile = objFSO.GetTempName() & ".hta"
Dim path : path = "HKCU\Volatile Environment\MsgResp"
 With tempFolder.CreateTextFile(tempFile)
    .Write "<input type=file name=f>" & _
     "<script>f.click();(new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'))" & _
     ".RegWrite('HKCU\\Volatile Environment\\MsgResp', f.value);" & _
     "close();</script>"
    .Close
 End With
 objSHL.Run tempFolder & "\" & tempFile, 0, True
 If objSHL.RegRead(path) = "" Then
  objSHL.RegDelete path
  objFSO.DeleteFile tempFolder & "\" & tempFile
  WScript.Quit
 End If
 SelectFile = objSHL.RegRead(path)
 objSHL.RegDelete path
 objFSO.DeleteFile tempFolder & "\" & tempFile
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------
objFSO.CopyFile SelectFile, SelectFold
```